# Produce a sequence $(g_n):g_n(x)\ge 0$ and $\lim g_n(x)\neq 0$ but $\int_{0}^{1} g_n\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

> Produce a sequence $(g_n):g_n(x)\ge 0,\,\forall x\in [0,1],\,\forall n\in\Bbb N$ and $\lim g_n(x)\neq 0,\,\forall x\in [0,1]$ but  $\int_{0}^{1} g_n\to 0$

Im in need to clarify that Im talking of the Riemann integral. I want some hint or example, Im unable to find a sequence like this. My work at this moment:

If the integral converges to zero then:

$$\int_{0}^{1}g_n=\lim_{m\to \infty}U(g_n,P_m)=k_n:(k_n)\to 0$$ I can find $(g_n)$ like these, by example $g_n(x)=x/n$, but Im unable to imagine something that hold at the same time the condition $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

I tried to thing something related to the Cantor set, the Tomae function or something like this but I dont found something useful yet :/

Comment: @M.T but what about $\lim g_n(x)\neq 0$?

Comment: Hi, by Fatou's lemma, the requirement that $\lim g_n \neq 0 \forall x$ can not be fulfilled.

Comment: Are you working with Riemann integrals or Lebesgue integrals? If Riemann, can't you take a standard example where $g_n\to 0$ and change all the functions at one point? Do you mean *for all $x$, $\lim g_n(x)\ne 0$*? Or do you mean *there exists an $x$ so that $\lim g_n(x)\ne 0$*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "standard" example is the sequence $\{g_n\}$ defined by
$$ g_1=1_{[0,1]},\; g_2=1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]},\;g_3=1_{[\frac{1}{2},1]},\; g_4=1_{[0,\frac{1}{4}]},\;g_5=1_{[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]},\dots$$

where $1_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$, i.e. $1_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $1_A(x)=0$ otherwise.

Note that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1g_n(x)\;dx=0$$
since the lengths of the intervals goes to zero, but $\limsup_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)=1$ for each $x\in[0,1]$.

The sequence $\{g_n\}$ is sometimes called the "typewriter sequence" or the "floating, shrinking interval".

Comment: First we split the interval $[0,1]$ into $1$ piece, then into $2$ pieces, then into $4$, then into $8$, and so on. It's possible to write down a formula for $g_n$, but it's kind of a pain and I think drawing a picture is much more helpful.